# GroovyTestCase throws groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method for Domain Classes

Tags: grails, groovy

I am writing my integration test using groovy and whenever i refer the domain class with methods like findBy ... i basically get an error that says groovy.lang.MissingMethodException.The exception however occurs only on my jenkins job but when i try to execute the test case locally(I mean from intellij ide) it seems to be fine.Any pointers?

I tried running the test from command line by running grails test-app --integration and i get the same error

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.sample.data.mpp.SourceSystem.methodMissing() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

Comment: Can you post the test code and full stacktrace?

Comment: Check if there is any `dependency` issue for the app in the jenkins box. If you have access to Jenkins box, try to run a `grails dependency-report` on the application, also add an example in question.

Comment: The test code looks like below   class ResponseControllerIntegrationTests extends GroovyTestCase

{



public void testFindByName()
 {
 
   assertNotNull(SourceSystem.findByName("SSP"))
 
  }



}

Comment: You must be using Spock? Otherwise mock the domain as findBy methods are generated at run time using meta programming and hence would not be available in tests.